# Microsoft Excel Filter function

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to filter entries containing short forms of words (for example "Rd" for "Road"), however the filter function for **containing "Rd"** would return me all entries with words containing "Rd" like forward, card etc.

Is there a way to filter entries with just the word "Rd" itself standing alone in the sentence and not being a part of other irrelevant words?

Comment: Can you filter for " Rd " with a leading and ending space?

Comment: Maybe only the leading one: `" Rd"`

Comment: What do you mean by leading and ending space?

Comment: But that only applies to the Ctrl+F function doesn't it? That would only point to me entries containing that but it doesn't filter results for me. Is there anything I can do with the Autofilter?

Comment: @user2964366 Of course. In your autofilter dialog, select `contains` and type ` Rd ` (notice the space before and after). This will filter all sentences where Rd stands alone. Note that this won't find Rd at the start or beginning of your sentence since the second space is missing there.

Comment: autofilter doesn't do that. maybe you can try it out yourself. But it does work for the find and replace function. Should I conclude that autofilter alone just doesn't do that work?

Answer (score 2):

This is a small adjustment to CLockeWork's solution.  If the helper column contined:

**=--ISNUMBER(FIND(" Rd"," " & A1 & " "))**

This will return 1 if the cell contains:

<>Rd<>

or begins with:

Rd<>

or ends with:

<>Rd

where <> represents the "space" character.

Comment: and so those are the entries that I do not want?

Comment: Either way....if you set the filter option on the helper column to **1** , then you will get all the **Rd** s.  Just try it out on some scrap data.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution: build an extra column with a formula that looks for short form words (without knowing more about your data I can't help specifically with the formula)

Then just filter on that column.

So if I knew I wanted to filter 2 letter words I could create a column with the formula:

```
=LEN($A2)=2
```

Or if using a table:

```
=LEN([@[TargetColumn])=2
```

Either of these would return a TRUE or FALSE value that you could then filter on.

Comment: It looks like the entry will contain that words "Rd" but not limit to those - like `Abbey Rd`. Therefore I don't think you can filter by the lenght.

Comment: This would work, but I think the OP has other words in the cells, like `main rd`

Comment: Yes, my excel entries are all sentences so I'm looking for entries that contain "Rd" as one of the words in the sentence but "Rd" as an independent serving as a shortform. For instance, "Accident at Abbey Rd" and "he is walking towards me": both will be given to me if I filter using the "containing" filter function. But I only want the first one.