# How can I filter data based on items in a list?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I filter entries containing any specific word in a list of words? For example, I have a list of road names in Singapore.

Amoy Street, Singapore
Ann Siang Hill
Anson Road
Arab Street
Armenian Street, Singapore
BBaghdad Street (Singapore)
Balestier Road
Banda Street
Bartley Road
Beach Road, Singapore
Bencoolen Street
Bernam Street
Boat Quay
Boon Tat Street
Boundary Road, Singapore
Bras Basah Road
Bugis Street
Bukit Batok Road
Bukit Pasoh Road
Bukit Timah Road
CCantonment Road, Singapore
Choa Chu Kang Road
Clarke Quay
Clementi Road
Club Street
Collyer Quay
Connaught Drive
Craig Road (Singapore)
Cross Street
 and many more

My spreadsheet has a large number of entries like the following, which may or may not contain road names mentioned in my list:

1. Saw an accident at Thomson Road
2. Found this by accident
3. 6 vehicles crashed at Balestier Road
4. I wanna crash now. So tired.
5. Bus collides with bicycle at Arab Street.
6. Accident at City Road.
7. You can crash my house later.

How do I filter to return entries that contains any road name identified in the list of names? How do I introduce an array/list of road names into Microsoft Excel and then relate it to a filter function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/670827/microsoft-excel-filter-function (created by the same user)

Comment: @douglaslps You're right. I voted to close the other question because this one has far more detail to it.

Comment: Can you define how many values you are checking for.  It seems possible that there are thousands, and the volume may exclude some possible answsers.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you want to match sentences that contain “Amoy Street”, you’ll need to remove the “, Singapore” from that first entry (and the others that contain it, and likewise with “(Singapore)”).  You may want to do this with a formula in a helper column, so let’s assume that your minimized list of road names is in cells `B1` through `B42`. 
And assume that your seven example sentences (or seventeen thousand, or however many you have) are in Column `C`.  Type

```
=AND(ISERROR(SEARCH(B$1:B$42, C1)))
```

into cell `D1` and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. 
This enters the formula as an *array formula*, causing it to appear in curly braces:
`{=AND(ISERROR(SEARCH(A$1:A$3, B1)))}`.  Drag/fill down to cover Column `C`. 
This will evaluate to FALSE for every sentence (`C` value) that contains a string from `B1:B42` and TRUE for every one that doesn’t. 
You can filter on that.  If you don’t like the fact that these values are “backwards”, just wrap the expression in a `NOT( )`:

```
=NOT(AND(ISERROR(SEARCH(B$1:B$42, C1))))
```

This is case insensitive. 
If you want it to be case sensitive, replace `SEARCH` with `FIND`.

This solution finds substrings.  Making it case sensitive reduces the likelihood
of false positives like “Banson Road” and “Uboat Quay”. 
If the road name will never appear at the beginning of a sentence, you can eliminate these substring match false positives by prepending a space to every road name in Column `B`. 
If a road name *can* appear at the beginning of a sentence,
then do that and change the formula to

> `=AND(ISERROR(SEARCH(B$1:B$42,`**`" " &`** `C1)))`

To handle “Mr. Connaught drives a Mercedes”, do the same thing but *append* the spaces. 
This still won’t handle “Does Mr. Connaught drive a Mercedes?”,
so you might want to go the case sensitive route.

I have tested this solution for a small number of strings. 
It is possible that it will fail if the list of roads is very long.

Answer (score 0):

Use AutoFilter with the **Contains...** option.  This will allow you to view items that contain a given text string within them.  Rows not contain the string will be hidden.

[Reference](http://www.contextures.com/xlautofilter01.html)

**EDIT #1** :

As James Jenkins pointed out, using AutoFilter with **Contains...**  will not allow a long list of  included sub-strings to be applied simutaneously...........here is an alternative VBA based approach.

Say we have a workbook with two tabs "roads" and "items".  The list of roads is in the "roads" tab starting at **A2**.  The list of items to be filtered is in the "items" tab starting at **A2**.

This macro first reads the roads list into an array.  The array is applied against each item in the items list.  Each item row is either hidden or displayed.

```
Sub FilterByList()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Set s1 = Sheets("roads")
    Set s2 = Sheets("items")
    Dim N1 As Long, N2 As Long, L1 As Long, L2 As Long
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range

    N1 = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    N2 = s2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim rds(1 To N1 - 1) As String
    For L = 2 To N1
        rds(L - 1) = s1.Cells(L, 1)
    Next L

    s2.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    For L2 = 2 To N2
        Set r2 = s2.Cells(L2, "A")
        v2 = r2.Value
        r2.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        For L1 = 2 To N1
            If InStr(1, v2, rds(L1 - 1)) > 0 Then
                r2.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        Next L1
    Next L2
End Sub
```

Comment: I do not think this will meet the OP's need

Comment: Hi James:    You may be right!...............I'll post some VBA as an alternative!

Answer (score -1):

You may use Advanced Filter.  Take a look at below post:

https://wmfexcel.com/2017/08/02/filter-a-lists-of-items-from-a-long-long-list/

Comment: Your answer should not just give a link to some external eresource (that could disappear). It should stand on its own. You can keep the link as a reference.